# redis high concurrency insertion

Tags: node.js, redis

I try to store comments in redis database. My data sctructure:

- `z` list where I hold commentId. Let us commentId = 3.
- And hash like `comment:3` with comment text, ip, useragent and comment time.

When I do [zadd](http://redis.io/commands/ZADD) first I get maximum Id from it, then plus 1 - it will be new Id.

The problem started when 2 comments are added at the same time. And they both can get the same Id and then in hash table one comment can be lost.

So how to compute newId without duplications on high concurrency?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wrap your two step procedure in [a Lua script](http://redis.io/commands/eval) and call that. Because redis is single-threaded, lua script invocations will be serialized ( = no race conditions).

### Alternative

Or you could store comment id in a separate key that you can [INCR](http://redis.io/commands/INCR). This way it should work even without wrapping both steps in a script.